# How can I connect an oracle data base with a dbml file?

Tags: .net, linq, oracle, linq-to-sql

I think the best way to use Oracle with LINQ is to map the data base tables into the dbml file by hand. Am I right?

When I have done it, then what? How can i connect the data base with the dbml file?

Answer (score 3):

There are 3rd party Linq providers for databases other than MSSQL:

[LinqToOracle](http://www.codeplex.com/LinqToOracle) and [DBLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/). The latter works also on SqLite, MySql, and such. So no, you don't have to create dbml files by hand.

There's also a nice and clear tutorial [here](http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/LINQ-To-MySQL.aspx) that explains how to get ready with DBLinq. Although it uses a MySql database as an example, that doesn't really matter, as you can just replace any MySql specific information with Oracle.

Comment: The tutorial link has since changed, it's now https://mikeborozdin.com/post/linq-to-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

This is another Oracle provider that supports the Entity Framework (not LinqToSQL): http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/ .