# How can I access a MySQL database with C# from functions within a class?

Tags: c#, mysql, class, linq-to-sql

I'm new to C# and asp.net programming and currently use MsSQL DataBases linked to my project with a DBML, using Linq to SQL, with my connection string in my web.config and all my database functions are stored in class managers. Examples below.

Connection string in web.config:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UserId;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Example Class Manager:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class DataManager
{
    private DataContext dc;

    public DataManager()
    {
        dc = new DataContext();
    }

    public News GetNews(int newsId)
    {
        return dc.News.Where(x => x.NewsId == newsId).Where(x => x.Deleted == false).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public News News_Save(News n)
    {
        if (n.NewsId == 0)
            dc.News.InsertOnSubmit(n);

        dc.SubmitChanges();

        return n;
    }
}
```

What I would like to know is how I can have a similar setup to this but to access a MySQL database. All the examples I have seen require creating a connection string within the page each time you want to use a function which seems wasteful and unnecessary to me. Is there anyway I can use my current structure but access a MySQL database with or without a DBML?

Comment: The way we used to do it in school was store our connection string in a globals file that we could access from our data access layer. See this: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10011720/retrieved-connection-string-storing-in-a-globalasa-file.aspx

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no up-to-date Linq-to-SQL provider for MySQL. But there is a MySQL provider for Entity Framework: [Connector/Net](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net). Entity Framework also supports LINQ, so your code would be pretty much the same.

You can use the built-in tools in Visual Studio (Project > Add New Item ... > ADO.NET Entity Data Model) to create your entities from an existing database and connection info will be stored in a .config file (I guess that would be web.config for a web/asp.net project).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't have a library to access mysql through linq but there are 3rd party providers. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704642/how-can-i-connect-an-oracle-data-base-with-a-dbml-file/704670#704670). That should mean you can keep your current manager class as-is (or maybe minor modifications to accommodate the 3rd party linq-to-mysql library).